# Too may query rows:50001

Tags: soql, sosl

There are more than 40,000 records in my production database. Whenever I Search using these queries I get this error:

> Too may query rows:50001

SOSL query:

```
String searchQuery = 'FIND \' '+searchStr1+ '\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact(id,AccountId,Name,Email,Years_of_Experience__c,Current_Location__c,Location__c,Date_Parsed_Text__c,CurrentDesignation__c  LIMIT 1000)';
```

SOQL query:

```
if ((selLocation==null|| selLocation=='')  && ( toYear==0 ) && ( fromYear==0 ) ) 
     {
    conList=[select Id,Name,Email,Current_Location__c,CurrentDesignation__c,Date_Parsed_Text__c,Years_of_Experience__c from contact where  Id IN:conId2  LIMIT 700  ];
     system.debug('rows'+Limits.getQueryRows());
     }
else if(selLocation!=null && ( toYear==0 ) && ( fromYear==0 ) )
    {
     conList=[select Id,Name,Email,Current_Location__c,CurrentDesignation__c,Date_Parsed_Text__c,Years_of_Experience__c from contact where Id IN:conId2 AND Current_Location__c=:selLocation  LIMIT 450 ];

    system.debug('rows'+Limits.getQueryRows());
    }
else if ((selLocation==null || selLocation=='') && toYear>0 && fromYear>=0 )
    {
     conList=[select Id,Name,Email,Current_Location__c,CurrentDesignation__c,Date_Parsed_Text__c,Years_of_Experience__c from contact where Id IN:conId2 AND ( Years_of_Experience__c>=:fromYear AND Years_of_Experience__c<=:toYear) LIMIT 450 ];

    system.debug('rows'+Limits.getQueryRows());
    }
else if((selLocation!=null || selLocation!='') && (toYear>0 && fromYear>=0) )
    {
     conList=[select Id,Name,Email,Current_Location__c,CurrentDesignation__c,Date_Parsed_Text__c,Years_of_Experience__c from contact where Id IN:conId2 AND ( Years_of_Experience__c>=:fromYear AND Years_of_Experience__c<=:toYear) AND Current_Location__c=:selLocation  LIMIT 450 ];

    system.debug('rows'+Limits.getQueryRows());
    }
```

How can I fix these errors?

Comment: Looks like some code containing queries is being executed withing a loop?

Comment: yes the if else loop in which i am applying the filter for the search string that i queried on the sosl query

Comment: Set<Id> conIds = new Map<Id, Contact>([SELECT Id FROM Contact]).keySet();
   
   conId2= new set<Id>();
   system.debug('*******'+conIds);
   
   List<List <sObject>> searchList = search.query(searchQuery);
   cList  = ((List<contact>)searchList[0]);
   for(Contact c1:clist){
   if(c1.AccountId=='0014100000GekPq')
   {
   conId2.add(c1.Id);
   }
   system.debug('conID2.SIZE :'+conId2.SIZE());
   }

this for loop is executed just after the sosl query and before the soql query

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to include any additional information, especially code.

Comment: So you are iterating the first query results and running SOQLs inside the loop? If so, then that is your problem. You should avoid using SOQLs inside loops.

Comment: I have kept the soql query out of the loop, as suggested by you, but still I am getting the 500001 error @RenatoOliveira

Comment: Otherwise, tell me how to limit my sosl search. Because when i am putting LIMIT in the sosl and soql query, it's still throwing same error. Infact it's not even considering a limit of 100.

Comment: Can you edit your original post with the whole method that you are trying to run?